# what shared instance and new instance

Tags: php, flightphp

from flightphp framework documention:

> By default, every time you load your class you will get a shared
>   instance. To get a new instance of a class, simply pass in false as a
>   parameter:

```
// Shared instance of the class
$shared = Flight::db(); 

// New instance of the class
$new = Flight::db(false);
```

what is shared instance?
what is difference between these two type in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flight::db() is a static method that returns an instance of the class.

Normally a singleton pattern is used, which means, if call Flight::db() several times, all variables point to the same instance.

if you call Flight::db(false), a new object is created for every call, which means if you call it several times, you get an own object for every call.

Comment: what if I call Flight::db() in multiple class and function? are they all point to the same instance?

Comment: that is exactly how a singleton is supposed to work. Whenever you call it, no matter from where, you always get the same instance, as long as you are in the same server call.